# How to generate a Gatling simulation class from HAR file via command prompt

Tags: testing, performance-testing, gatling

Is there a way to generate Gatling simulation class from a HAR via command prompt(with out opening Gatling recorder UI) ?

Idea is to generate a HAR file using browsermob-proxy, then convert it to Gatling simulation and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Got the below answer from Gatling google groups.

"Having a "command line mode" for the Recorder is something that we plan to do for Gatling 2.1, but it is currently not possible."

[Link to google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/0wSkqZW7oig)